# Call Ajax function before tab change event in vue form wizard

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-form-wizard vue wizard and i want to call ajax function before tab change event like this :

```
beforeTabSwitch: function(tab){
if(tab===2)
{
   this.formData
        .post(APP_URL + `/api/validate-data`, { headers: header })
        .then((response) => {

          if (response.status==1) {
            return true;
          }
          else 
          {
            return false;
          }
          
        });
}
},
```

I have used this code but as i call ajax request then it get stuck in infinite loop

Comment: See my answer, I have updated the example specifically for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beforeTabSwitch`, check the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/42vpr5hq/).

You should return the `true` or `false` from the `beforeTabSwitch` function not the inner function.

e.g.

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert('Yay. Done!');
   },
   beforeTabSwitch: async(tab) => {
     let flag = false;
     await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        flag = true;
        resolve("done");
      }, 1500);
    }).then();
    return flag;
   }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue is when i place ajax function in beforeTabSwitch i'm getting this error : [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function after removing this ajax function it is working

Comment: @user3653474 it is because you are not returning anything from the `beforeTabSwitch` function, you are returning the boolean from the ajax function which should not work.